# How to use UPDATE ... FROM in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to write this kind of statement in SQLAlchemy / Postgres:

```
UPDATE slots
  FROM (SELECT id FROM slots WHERE user IS NULL
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000) AS available
   SET user='joe'
 WHERE id = available.id
 RETURNING *;
```

Namely, I would like to update a limited number of rows matching specified criteria.

PG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it this way:

```py
limited_slots = select([slots.c.id]).\
    where(slots.c.user==None).\
    order_by(slots.c.id).\
    limit(1000)
stmt = slots.update().returning(slots).\
    values(user='joe').\
    where(slots.c.id.in_(limited_slots))
```

I don't think its as efficient as the original SQL query, however if the database memory is large enough to hold all related segments it shouldn't make much difference.

Answer (score -2):

It's been a while since I used sqlalchemy so consider the following as pseudocode:

```
for i in session.query(Slots).filter(Slots.user == None):
    i.user = "Joe"
    session.add(i)

session.commit()
```

I recommend  the [sqlalchemy ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html).

Comment: Down voted because this does not answer the question.